# AWS lambda handler and MySQL database. Inserted row by a first client connection is not visible by a second client connection

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, transactions, aws-lambda, pymysql

I cannot understand why values inserted by a first AWS lambda function (in Python) are not visible by another AWS lambda function (using a different MySql client connection). Here what I'm doing:

Handler A:

```
conn = DBConnectionFactory.create()
// conn.thread_id() returns X
```

Handler B:

```
conn = DBConnection.instance()
// conn.thread_id() returns Y
```

Handler A:

```
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table (id, ...) VALUES ('myid', ...)")
conn.commit()
```

Then I check with a command line that the new row has been correctly inserted --> OK

Handler B:

```
// client B 
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 'myid'");
```

Here the last query does not return the newly created row. Why ? 
Howevere if I use a new connection with handler B it works

Handler B:

```
conn = DBConnection.instance()
// conn.thread_id() returns Z
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 'myid'"); 
    // OK the row is found !!
```

---

I've tested locally with a local database and it's working well:

```
conn1 = DBConnectionFactory.create();
conn2 = DBConnectionFactory.create();

with conn2.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table (id, ...) VALUES(X, ...)")
conn2.commit()

with conn1.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = X')
    print(cursor.rowcount) // OK working I have 1 row
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of transaction isolation.

If you are reading something from database in B before A inserts then B uses the database state (snapshot) from the time before A has inserted (and committed) and keeps reading this snapshot even after A has committed.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

```
             Session A              Session B    
time
|          SELECT * FROM t;
|          empty set
|                                 INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 2);
|
v          SELECT * FROM t;
           empty set
                                  COMMIT;

           SELECT * FROM t;
           empty set

           COMMIT;

           SELECT * FROM t;
           ---------------------
           |    1    |    2    |
           ---------------------
```

Note that I use the assumption that you are reading something in B before A inserts+commits. I cannot see your complete source so I don't know if that's true, but I think it most probably is :)

Commit/rollback transaction in B and then B should see the row inserted by A.

```
# client B 
conn.rollback() # or conn.commit()
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 'myid'")
```

This behavior also depends on isolation level settings.